# Ошибка при работе с input

Tags: javascript

В этой строке:

```
!!checkMobileOperator.check(input.val()) && submit.removeprop('disabled');
```

выбивает ошибку: `Uncaught TypeError: checkMobileOperator.check is not a function`

Вот весь код: http://jsfiddle.net/t52ka/28/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вопрос в том, что это за ошибка, то:

> У объекта checkMobileOperator нет метода check

**UPDATE**:

Я бы написал так:

Объявление:

```
var checkMobileOperator = (function() {
    return {
        check: checkFunction
    };

    function checkFunction(arg) {
        // logic
        return result;
    }
})();
```

....
где-то далее
....

```
checkMobileOperator.check(arg)
```

Comment: исправил ошибки на которые   вы указали :    http://jsfiddle.net/t52ka/30/                                 теперь вот здесь вылезла  : var checkMobileOperator = new checkMobileOperator();   не подскажите как её исправить ?

Answer (score 2):

Очень много ошибок в коде:

1. Не определена переменная `which`;
2. Вы создали объект `CheckMobileOperator`, а метод `check` пытаетесь вызвать у функции `сheckMobileOperator`;
3. Следом вас ждет ошибка с методом `submit.removeprop` которого нету, а есть `submit.removeProp`;

В JavaScript имеет значение регистр идентификаторов. Постарайтесь обращать на это внимание. И уделите внимание оформлению кода.

Comment: Плюсую за дельную критику

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, вроде даже не критиковал. Показал где ошибки и посоветовал на что обратить внимание. ТС явно осваивается с JS, чего же тут критиковать. Все когда-то начинают

Comment: ну как бы это она и есть =)

Comment: Я удивлен как ТС обнаружил ошибку с методом check. Я пока не исправил `which` на `e.which` получал совсем другие ошибки